# could not resolve state "home.app.detail" from state "home.apps.list", UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page showing the list of applications that I want to be able to go to the page of the details of the app, when I click on each one of them.
Here is my config:

```
module bandar {
  'use strict';

  export class RouterConfig {
    /** @ngInject */
    constructor($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider,
                $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider,
                $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'app/components/main/main.html',
          controller: 'MainController',
          controllerAs: 'mainCtrl'
        })
        .state('home.apps', {
          url: '/apps',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/apps.html',
          controller: 'AppsController',
          controllerAs: 'appsCtrl',
        })
        .state('home.apps.list', {
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/list.html',
        })
        .state('home.app.detail', {
          url: '/app/:package_name',
          templateUrl: 'app/components/apps/app.html',
          controller: 'AppController',
          controllerAs: 'appCtrl',
        });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/apps');
      /*$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');*/
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the part of the list template which is anchoring to the app's details page:

```
<a ui-sref="home.app.detail({package_name: app.package_name})">{{app.title}}</a>
```

But when I hit it in my browser, the following error occurs in the console:

```
Error: Could not resolve 'home.app.detail' from state 'home.apps.list'
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3140)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3068)
    at angular-ui-router.js:4181
    at angular.js:17682
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5387)
    at angular.js:5659
```

I guess the problem is `UI-Router` thinks that I'm pointing at the state relatively, but I wanna do it in the absolute way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is parent name *`'home.app'`* instead of **`'home.apps'`**

```
// wrong
.state('home.app.detail', { ...
// should be
.state('home.apps.detail', { ...
```

because parent is

```
.state('home.apps', { ...
```

EXTEND in case, that this should not be child of 'home.apps' we have to options

1) do not inherit at all

```
.state('detail', { ...
```

2) introduce the parent(s) which is(are) used in the dot-state-name-notation

```
// exists already
.state('home', { ...
// this parent must be declared to be used later
.state('home.app', {
// now we can use parent 'home.app' because it exists
.state('home.app.detail', {
```

Comment: Well, then you have two options, both are in my extended answer.